# If Else with a twist - maybe

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Can i make a If Else-statement that finishes a div before doing "else"?
I want to cycle through my posts and put the posts from "specialCat" in one div.

```
<div id="the-div-i-want-to-close">  

<?php if (in_category('specialCat')) { ?> 

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php }  else { ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to modify the query calling your special category then finishing the loop with the rest of the posts.

```
 <?php
    $args = array(
    'category_name' => 'special-cat', // Use Category slug
    'posts_per_page' => -1 // Get all the post in SpecialCat
    );
    $special_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <div id="the-div-i-want-to-close"> 
    <?php
    while ( $special_query->have_posts() ) : $special_query->the_post();
    $no_repeat[] = $post->ID ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div> <?php // Close your special div after looping through all SpecialCat posts

// Start the loop again 

    if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if (in_array( $post->ID, $no_repeat ) ) continue;  // Exclude the posts we already got above ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works as a charm! Had no idea that you could restart 'the loop'.

Answer (score 0):

You can include HTML within a for each loop, so long as you close the PHP tags (or include the HTML in an echo statement).

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it for you?

```
<div id="the-div-i-want-to-close">  
<?php $isOpen = true; ?>
<?php if (in_category('specialCat')) { ?> 
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php }  else { ?>
    <?php if($isOpen) { ?>
    </div>
    <?php $isOpen = false; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i would if i only had one other post. But when i have more than one then it closes the div every time it displays a post that is not in 'specialCat'. I need something like "if (do this) beforeElse (close div) else (do this)"

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your comment (Added a variable called $isOpen to flag whether we need to close the div).  It does beg the question - what happens if you have multiple posts that are in the specialCat category?  In that case, you may want to handle opening and closing your div inside the if block...

Comment: i have multiple posts in both cats. But i think you got me started out! I'll just try it out and then return :)